# add folder to 7z with current date in front

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, 7-zip

I have a folder `Foo` that I want to backup to `Foo.2018.07.12.7z`

and so far I tried this command:

```
C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z a "Foo%DATE%".7z Foo
```

but the problem is that my date format has slashes so it creates nested folders like: `Foo12\7\2018.7z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to get date/time in a locale/user settings independent format.

Here are two different ways to achieve this:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\12\SU_1338640.cmd
@Echo off

:: use wmic to get date in a locale/user settings independent format
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set _DT=%%A
Set "Archive=Foo.%_DT:~0,4%.%_DT:~4,2%.%_DT:~6,2%.7z"
Echo Archive=%Archive%

:: use powershell to get date in a locale/user settings independent format
for /f %%A in (
  'Powershell -Nop -C "Get-Date -f yyyy.MM.dd" '
) do Set "_DT=%%A"
Set "Archive=Foo.%_DT%.7z"
Echo Archive=%Archive%
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\12\SU_1338640.cmd
Archive=Foo.2018.07.12.7z
Archive=Foo.2018.07.12.7z
```

Comment: powershell is good

Answer (score 1):

Here's the batch solution I'd use to perform this operation just as you specified but with a slightly different syntax and a bit more explicit. I'd also use [date](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html) and [variable substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to set the date in the proper format as you desire but I'd name the date variable `%Dt%` and not `%DATE%`.

---

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO OFF

SET Dt=%date:~10%.%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%
SET SrcFolder=C:\Test\Foo
SET DestPath=C:\Destination\Folder

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a "%DestPath%\Test.%Dt%.7z" "%SrcFolder%"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [date](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html)
- [variable substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Comment: @Omu - Please note for the `Dt=` variable substring parsing I used to get the format, this is when the OS date format is set to `<day> mm/dd/yyyy` format so if this does not work in your case, tell me the format which you see the date string and I'll adjust accordingly. From command line just `echo %date%` and tell me the output and I'll adjust accordingly. I do know more universal methods if absolutely needed but the rest of your logic was pretty accurate so I assume it was just the date you needed help with more than anything.