# How to run a batch (xcopy) involving a network drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I would like to run this batch on a windows server 2008 :

```
SET "DateToday=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%"
echo %DateToday%
mkdir C:\Log_%DateToday% 
xcopy /y "\\sf1coeur\AXA-CASH\GFPz %DateToday%" C:\Log_%DateToday% /i
```

But when I try to run it manually, I have the following error: "Invalid drive specification"

So I thought I would run the batch with the task scheduler to use another user because I think the batch is running as a SYSTEM, so it does not know the path to the network drive.

The scheduled task runs fine but the batch does not work and I do not have an error message.

Can you help me ?

Comment: *when I try to run it manually, I have the following error: "Invalid drive specification"* If replace `"\\sf1coeur\AXA-CASH\GFPz %DateToday%"` with some local file pathname - copy process do not fails? While opening `\\sf1coeur` - do you see `AXA-CASH` shared resource? can you open it and see the `GFPz %DateToday%` file?

Comment: When i replace  `"\\sf1coeur\AXA-CASH\GFPz %DateToday%"` with a local file pathname,copy process does not fail. `\\sf1coeur\AXA-CASH\` is the name of the network drive. I can open it and see the `GFPz %DateToday%` file.

Comment: depeding on your date format `MM/dd/yyyy` there might be a leading space, so the folder is `C:\Log_ 7132018` and you don't double quote the folder name. Better get the [date in a locale/user setting independent format](https://superuser.com/a/1338669/639112)

Comment: There are no leading space, the folder is `C:\Log_20180713` and he is well created

Comment: FYI.... I have experienced something similar in the past with `xcopy` command and it parsing characters out of the `%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%` formatted string so even though it `echo`'s correctly, I've seen `xcopy` not interpret that string correctly and not just the trailing or leading areas of the string just FYI... In that case, I recall vaguely just using `copy` instead since it was for a single file so consider that. You might be able to `>>` output of `xcopy with /y /f` to see this I think.... vague recollection though. I think it's how `xcopy` sees `%DateToday%`—inaccurately.

Comment: Additionally, I would use ``C:\Log_%DateToday%\`` in case that's the case and it needs the ending backslash as I always use that when copying to a directory so consider adding the ending ``\`` to the destination directory as that may actually be the issue. I think the other issue was when I used `xcopy` with an output name to destination and that having that other issue but you can output with the `/y /f` to see the full paths, etc.

Comment: I have found the solution !  I forgot to do a NET USE on the network drive